# Use Shopify Script Editor to Set Static Price by Tag

Tags: ruby, shopify

I've examined similar questions and solutions but I was not able to get them to work with mine.  I need to have a bunch of products set to a static price of $50,  there is no specific discount I can apply as the actual price on these all vary.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
class StaticPrice

  def initialize(selector)
    @selector = selector
  end
```

TagSelector

```
 class TagSelector

      def initialize(tag)
        @tag = tag
      end

      def match?(line_item)
        line_item.variant.product.tags.include?(@tag)
      end

    end

CAMPAIGNS = [
  StaticPrice.new(
    TagSelector.new("boots"),
    line_item.line_price == (5000), message: "SALE!")
]


Output.cart = Input.cart
```

**** UPDATE... Well I got it to work, however it's extremely bloated and I'm quite sure unprofessional (rookie here), but.. it works.. This allows me to set static prices on products based off tags for a particular sale while at the same time not allowing someone to use a coupon to get any additional price off of the sale item.. I appreciate any suggestions for improvement ****

```
case Input.cart.discount_code
when CartDiscount::Percentage
          if  Line_items.quantity > 1
            Input.cart.discount_code.reject(message: "Coupons can not be combined with BOGO promotion")
          end
        end

class ItemCampaign
  def initialize(selector, discount, partitioner)
    @selector = selector
    @discount = discount
    @partitioner = partitioner
  end
  def run(cart)
    applicable_items = cart.line_items.select do |line_item|
      @selector.match?(line_item)
    end
    discounted_items = @partitioner.partition(cart, applicable_items)

    discounted_items.each do |line_item|
      @discount.apply(line_item)
    end
  end
end
class TagSelector
  def initialize(tag)
    @tag = tag
  end
  def match?(line_item)
    line_item.variant.product.tags.include?(@tag)
  end
end
class PercentageDiscount50
  def initialize(percent, message)
    @percent = Money.new(cents: 100) * 50
    @message = message
  end
  def apply(line_item)
    line_discount = line_item.line_price - line_item.line_price + Money.new(cents: 100) * 50
    new_line_price = Money.new(cents: 100) * 50
    line_item.change_line_price(new_line_price, message: @message)
    puts "Discounted line item with variant #{line_item.variant.id} by #{line_discount}."
  end
end
class PercentageDiscount40
  def initialize(percent, message)
    @percent = Money.new(cents: 100) * 40
    @message = message
  end
  def apply(line_item)
    line_discount = line_item.line_price - line_item.line_price + Money.new(cents: 100) * 40
    new_line_price = Money.new(cents: 100) * 40
    line_item.change_line_price(new_line_price, message: @message)
    puts "Discounted line item with variant #{line_item.variant.id} by #{line_discount}."
  end
end
class PercentageDiscount30
  def initialize(percent, message)
    @percent = Money.new(cents: 100) * 30
    @message = message
  end
  def apply(line_item)
    line_discount = line_item.line_price - line_item.line_price + Money.new(cents: 100) * 30
    new_line_price = Money.new(cents: 100) * 30
    line_item.change_line_price(new_line_price, message: @message)
    puts "Discounted line item with variant #{line_item.variant.id} by #{line_discount}."
  end
end
class PercentageDiscount20
  def initialize(percent, message)
    @percent = Money.new(cents: 100) * 20
    @message = message
  end
  def apply(line_item)
    line_discount = line_item.line_price - line_item.line_price + Money.new(cents: 100) * 20
    new_line_price = Money.new(cents: 100) * 20
    line_item.change_line_price(new_line_price, message: @message)
    puts "Discounted line item with variant #{line_item.variant.id} by #{line_discount}."
  end
end
class PercentageDiscount10
  def initialize(percent, message)
    @percent = Money.new(cents: 100) * 10
    @message = message
  end
  def apply(line_item)
    line_discount = line_item.line_price - line_item.line_price + Money.new(cents: 100) * 10
    new_line_price = Money.new(cents: 100) * 10
    line_item.change_line_price(new_line_price, message: @message)
    puts "Discounted line item with variant #{line_item.variant.id} by #{line_discount}."
  end
end
class LowToHighPartitioner
  def initialize(paid_item_count, discounted_item_count)
    @paid_item_count = paid_item_count
    @discounted_item_count = discounted_item_count
  end
  def partition(cart, applicable_line_items)
    sorted_items = applicable_line_items.sort_by{|line_item| line_item.variant.price}
    total_applicable_quantity = sorted_items.map(&:quantity).reduce(0, :+)
    discounted_items_remaining = Integer(total_applicable_quantity / (@paid_item_count + @discounted_item_count) * @discounted_item_count)
    discounted_items = []
    sorted_items.each do |line_item|
      break if discounted_items_remaining == 0
      discounted_item = line_item
      if line_item.quantity > discounted_items_remaining
        discounted_item = line_item.split(take: discounted_items_remaining)
        position = cart.line_items.find_index(line_item)
        cart.line_items.insert(position + 0, discounted_item)
      end
      discounted_items_remaining -= discounted_item.quantity
      discounted_items.push(discounted_item)
    end
    discounted_items
  end
end
CAMPAIGNS = [
  ItemCampaign.new(
    TagSelector.new("SCRIPT50"),
    PercentageDiscount50.new(10, "$50 FINAL SALE!"),
    LowToHighPartitioner.new(0,1),
  ),
  ItemCampaign.new(
    TagSelector.new("SCRIPT40"),
    PercentageDiscount40.new(10, "$40 FINAL SALE!"),
    LowToHighPartitioner.new(0,1),
  ),
    ItemCampaign.new(
    TagSelector.new("SCRIPT30"),
    PercentageDiscount30.new(10, "$30 FINAL SALE!"),
    LowToHighPartitioner.new(0,1),
  ),
    ItemCampaign.new(
    TagSelector.new("SCRIPT20"),
    PercentageDiscount20.new(10, "$20 FINAL SALE!"),
    LowToHighPartitioner.new(0,1),
  ),
    ItemCampaign.new(
    TagSelector.new("SCRIPT10"),
    PercentageDiscount10.new(10, "$10 FINAL SALE!"),
    LowToHighPartitioner.new(0,1),
  )
]
CAMPAIGNS.each do |campaign|
  campaign.run(Input.cart)
end
Output.cart = Input.cart
```

Comment: Not sure if this is whats causing your error but upon formatting your code you are missing an `end` for your `StaticPrice` class

Answer (score 0):

When you are instantiating a new StaticPrice object, you are sending in 3 attributes but your object accepts only the one. You instantiate TagSelector, but you never use the match? method.

Without knowing more, seeing more, and having more of your explanations, the amount of code you are providing is of little use.

Why not just iterate the cart, and set prices. That is trivial and does not involve complex objects. Experiment with simpler code, and build up to a more organized approach as you gain confidence. There is little need for the campaign, StaticPrice and TagSelector till you actually have some working script code that exhibits a need for them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, I'm afraid I'm not very good at this and I'm up against a wall to have this thing working by Monday and I can't find anyone to write it for me so I'm trying to Frankenstein something together quickly based off of the pre-existing scripts (not many) in shopify and some of the stuff I've found on GitHub.. 

If you or anyone has an easy way to do this I would be eternally grateful, sorry for being needy, I'm trying to advance my skills to be able to actually assist rather than just ask for help.

Comment: Hey guys,  well I managed to get it to work, I'm posting my results here mostly for comic relief, I'm certain this is bloated code with a ton of unnecessary stuff going on, but I got it to work.  Basically this will change the price of items in the cart based on their tag for a sale and limit anyone from combining a coupon with the prices.